# Login to sql server reporting services in JAVA

Tags: java, reporting-services

I'm using SSRS with JAVA web application, I successfully generated the reports with passing the parameters and the report format dynamically, but I'm facing an issue with the reporting services login prompt there, I want to stop this prompt and instead adding the reporting services user credentials in the back-end using JAVA. But it did not work and I'm really confused.

**What is it the right way to do so? Is there something I'm missing and/or that I need to do? Is there any other way to do this?**

I've imported the web service classes into my project and tried to set the user credential using `LogonUser` in the `ReportExecutionServiceSoap` object as:

```
reportExecutionServiceSoap.logonUser(username,pwd,"");
```

But this has not worked for me.

---

**EDIT:**

> Microsoft.ReportingServices.Diagnostics.Utilities.LogonFailedException: Logon attempt for user ..... failed., Microsoft.ReportingServices.Diagnostics.Utilities.LogonFailedException: Log on failed. Ensure the user name and password are correct.;

Although I'm sure that the credentials I've passed are correct and it's working fine when using the login prompt to pass the same credentials.

Comment: @Tatranskymedved
ERROR: Microsoft.ReportingServices.Diagnostics.Utilities.LogonFailedException: Logon attempt for user ..... failed., Microsoft.ReportingServices.Diagnostics.Utilities.LogonFailedException: Log on failed. Ensure the user name and password are correct.; 
although I'm sure that the credentials I've passed are correct and it's working fine when using the login prompt to pass the same credentials

Comment: Do You have correct connection string? Are You connecting to the right server?

Comment: yes it's connecting to the right server and i can find the error in the ReportServerService logs file in the server